# 'dict' object has no attribute 'coupon' ecommerce/store/views.py, line 254, in add_coupon

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I have this e-commerce website I'm creating with `django3`
and I am getting this problem.

```
AttributeError at /add-coupon/
'dict' object has no attribute 'coupon'
```

if someone can help please!!!

**my views**

```
def get_coupon(request, code):
    try:
        coupon = Coupon.objects.get(code = code)
        return coupon
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        messages.info(request, 'This coupon does not exist')
        return redirect('checkout')


    def add_coupon(request):
        data = cartData(request)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CouponForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                try:
                    code = form.cleaned_data.get('code')
                    order = data['order']
                    order.coupon = get_coupon(request, code)
                    order.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Successfully added coupon!')
                    return redirect('checkout')
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    messages.info(request, 'You do not have an active order')
                    return redirect('checkout')
        return redirect('checkout')
```

**my guest order function**

```
def guestOrder(request, data):
    name = data['form']['name']
    email = data['form']['email']

    cookieData = cookieCart(request)
    items = cookieData['items']

    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
            username = name,
            email=email,
            )
    #user.name = name
    user.save()

    order = Order.objects.create(
        user=user,
        complete=False,
        coupon=None, #todelete
        )

    for item in items:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=item['id'])
        orderItem = OrderItem.objects.create(
            product=product,
            order=order,
            quantity=item['quantity'],
        )
    return user, order
```

Comment: should it be  ```order['coupon'] = get_coupon(request, code)`` ?

Comment: Share also your `cartData` code. Your data['order'] is a dict, no Class Object.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Can you check my new question? I put all the details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66142992/line-254-in-add-coupon-order-coupon-get-couponrequest-code-attributeerror